# Gender via Google People API

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-signin, google-people-api

Using Google People API, I'm having problems getting information about gender via https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me and correct access_token (it is correct because it influences whether information like nickname and locale appear).

I am asking for scope "profile email openid".

I can get a gender, but only for users who made that information public, but not from those who do have it filled, but set as private, which kind of defeats the purpose of asking for private profile information.

Is there a way to get private gender via any combination of Google API and scope?

Thank you

Comment: you might like to look at this discussion of how to ask about gender, and whether you actually need to ask users for their gender https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/90123/is-my-gender-selection-sexist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, there are no scopes that return private gender information.

Comment: it is inconsistency in google people api, birthday can be retrieved even it is private but not for gender

Comment: I created FR here, please start if it is helpful https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/117744553