# Unable to get gender from Google People API

Tags: google-api, google-apis-explorer, google-people-api

I've got a problem obtaining gender information from People API.

I'm making a request to https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/`account_id` which is not returning gender field. If I add `genders` to `personFields` it is giving me `Requested entity was not found` error.

It looks like obtaining this information is forbidden. Is there any chance to get this field?

Comment: The user has to fill it out and set it to public.

Comment: @DalmTo Of course it is in both cases

Comment: what if you use people/me not account id ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, because I'm using this API to log-in user to my webpage. Or did I misunderstood the concept of this API?

Comment: I think you should look into this https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect

Comment: There probably is no possibility to replace my solution to OpenID Connect. 
I've successfully managed to login and register customers through my current solution and obtain their gender from Google Accounts which were created months ago. It doesn't work only with new accounts.

Comment: Google people api is for accessing data about a persons contacts in Google.  It has nothing to do with authenticating a user to your website.

Comment: I can see here: [link](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) there is a personField `genders`. Why can't I obtain this information even from quoted site?

Comment: This is most likely as @DaImTo suggested that the gender is NOT public. As said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324890/gender-via-google-people-api, if the gender is NOT public you won't get it. New users that sign up very rarely set gender to public. How are you sure that that gender is set to public?

You should have the user visit https://aboutme.google.com/ and have them verify that Gender is shared publicly.

Comment: Google People API doesn't have anything to do with the act of logging in. It's only for fetching user data. So using `people/me` should be fine if the user is logged in. If the user is not logged in, you can't use it and it will only fetch public data.

If you haven't logged in the user, then you should see https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to use the Google People api.

The first assumes that you have used Oauth2 to authenticate your user.

> GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me

returns the info about the current authenticated user.

The second is a public call to the api. you can use an API key or Oauth2.

> GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/117200475532672775346

This will return the info about a specific user {117200475532672775346} but it will depend upon what that user has set to public.  The above number is my personal g+ account, the following is the gender response.

```
"genders": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "117200475532672775346"
        }
      },
      "value": "female",
      "formattedValue": "Female"
    }
```

I have no idea where you are getting your account id this is a users google id.  The information must be filled out on Google plus i suggest you check the users google+ account to see what they have set to public https://plus.google.com/u/0/117200475532672775346.   Note: It doesn't matter if this is the current authenticated user if they dont have the info set public you cant see it in your application.

Tip: assuming you only want to see genders you can use the fields parameter to request just that

> ?fields=genders